# Python Docker - bind source path does not exist

Tags: python, docker, volume, mount

I basically want to run an external docker container within another docker container using the python docker client. Basically the python script, which will be run inside the docker container will pull in an image and then run the container. I tried running the standalone python script locally first, and didn't have any issues. Now when I try running the script from inside a docker container, it fails with the following error:

```
docker.errors.APIError: 400 Client Error for http+docker://localhost/v1.41/containers/create: Bad Request ("invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /code/User_Input.json")
```

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM python3.7

WORKDIR /code

USER root

COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r /code/requirements.txt
COPY ./main.py /code/main.py
COPY ./config.json /code/config.json
COPY ./templates/ /code/


CMD ["python3", "main.py"]
```

And here is a snippet of my Python script:

```
client.images.pull(docker_image)

cwd = os.getcwd()

with open(f"{cwd}/User_Input.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(user_input, f)

# Mount the current directory to /code/hostcwd
volumes = {cwd: {"bind": "/home/hostcwd", "mode": "rw"}}

# Mount the input json file to /User_Input.json inside the container
mounts = [
        docker.types.Mount(
            type="bind", source=f"{cwd}/User_Input.json", target="/User_Input.json", read_only=False
        )
    ]

container = client.containers.run(
        docker_image,
        command=None,
        volumes=volumes,
        environment=env_vars,
        mounts=mounts,
        stdin_open=True,
        stdout=True,
        stderr=True,
        remove=True,
        tty=True,
        detach=True,
    )

for line in container.logs(stream=True):
    print(line.decode("utf-8"), end="")
```

I am confused because it's complaining that the bind source path doesn't exist, but I'm manually creating the file to that designated path in my python script and when I ssh into the container, I see the `User_Input.json`.

Comment: Bind mounts are always interpreted in the context where the Docker daemon is running.  If you're making this API call from a container and Docker is on the host, the `source` will always be a path on the host filesystem.  You cannot mount files from one container to another.

Comment: Thanks David - So what is a workaround for this then? I need to pass this file into the container run

Comment: Could you for example run a Flask server in the other container, and HTTP POST the file to it, without involving the Docker API at all?

Comment: I guess so but these are utility images owned by another team and modifying the source code for these containers would be a lot of work...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's not possible to mount files from one container to another. As a workaround, you can use the docker client to build a new image. You can have a `COPY` command in the new docker build which will copy the file(s) from the the source folder inside the container to the new docker's working directory. In this way, you no longer need to rely on docker `volumes` and `mounts`.

Here is an example of the implementation:

```
with open(f"./User_Input.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(user_input, f)

dockerfile = f"""
FROM {docker_image}
COPY ./User_Input.json ./
"""

with open("Dockerfile", "w") as f:
    f.write(dockerfile)

new_image, build_logs = client.images.build(path=".", quiet=False, tag="latest")

container = client.containers.run(
        new_image,
        command=None,
        environment=env_vars,
        stdin_open=True,
        stdout=True,
        stderr=True,
        remove=True,
        tty=True,
        detach=True,
    )
```